# Somente o último case do switch é executado

Tags: javascript, html5

Estou criando uma página onde quando o cliente selecionar o modelo de alguma placa, a altura e a largura da parede, vai exibir na tela valores baseado na placa que o cliente selecionou. Porém, somente os valores do último case do `switch` é executado.

Os outros cases não são executados, mesmo o usuário selecionando o modelo 4 estrelas; no momento de exibir os valores, mostra os valores do modelo eclipse, que é a ultima opção do `switch`.

```
<select id="calcOrcamento" class="form-control" required="required" name="modelo" onBlur="validaModelo(this); ">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Selecione um Modelo</option>
    <option id="estrelas"   value="7"  >4 Entrelas    </option>
    <option id="piramide"    value="10" >Pirâmide     </option>
    <option id="eclipse"     value="7"  >Eclipse      </option>
    <option id="concavo"     value="7"  >Côncavo      </option>
    <option id="quadradinha" value="16" >Quadradinha  </option>
    <option id="onda"        value="8"  >Onda         </option>
    <option id="mosaico"     value="13" >Mosaico      </option>
    <option id="santome"     value="10" >Santo Mé     </option>
</select>

<div id="exibe"></div>

<div>
    <input type="button" value="Calcular" onClick="calculaValor();"/>
</div>

function calculaValores(modelo,altura,largura){
    var area = altura*largura;
    var calc = parseFloat((area*modelo).toFixed(2));
    var valor = parseFloat((area*120).toFixed(2));
    document.getElementById('exibe').innerHTML = "<b>Quantidade de Placas: " + calc + "<br> Valor Instalação: " + valor + "</b>";
    document.calculaOrc.submit;
}

function calculaValor(){
    var estrelas    = (document.getElementById('estrelas')    ,'4estrelas'  );
    var piramide    = (document.getElementById('piramide')    ,'piramide'   );
    var eclipse     = (document.getElementById('eclipse')     ,'eclipse'    );
    var concavo     = (document.getElementById('concavo')     ,'concavo'    );
    var quadradinha = (document.getElementById('quadradinha') ,'quadradinha');
    var onda        = (document.getElementById('onda')        ,'onda'       );
    var mosaico     = (document.getElementById('mosaico')     ,'mosaico'    );
    var santome     = (document.getElementById('santome')     ,'santome'    );
    var placa       = [estrelas,piramide,eclipse,concavo,quadradinha,onda,mosaico,santome];

    var altura      = document.getElementById('altura') .value;
    var largura     = document.getElementById('largura').value;
    var i;
    for(i=0 ; i<=placa.length ; i++){
        switch(placa[i]){
            case '4estrelas':
                var estrela = (document.getElementById('estrelas').value);
                calculaValores(estrela,altura,largura);
                break;

            case 'piramide':
                var piramide = (document.getElementById('piramide').value);
                calculaValores(piramide,altura,largura);
                break;

            case 'eclipse':
                var eclipse = (document.getElementById('eclipse').value);
                calculaValores(eclipse,altura,largura);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

  function validaModelo(modelo){
        var msg = "Modelo Inválido.";
        var info = "Selecionar um Modelo";

        if(modelo.value == ''){
            estilizandoErro(modelo,msg,info);

        }
    }

 function estilizandoErro(variavel,msg,info){
        variavel.value = "";
        variavel.placeholder = msg;
        variavel.style.borderColor = "#ff0000";
        variavel.style.outline = "#ff0000";
        variavel.focus();
        variavel.onkeydown = function keydown_nome(){
            variavel.placeholder = info;
            variavel.style.borderColor = "#999999";
            variavel.style.outline = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Você tem a função `validaModelo()` se puder postar facilita, pq completa o código pra poder testar 100%

Comment: Blz, vou postar o restante

Comment: Do jeito que está, o `placa[i]` sempre vai dar "4estrelas", que é o primeiro index [0] da Array `placas`. Logo o switch vai sempre parar no primeiro `case '4estrelas'`.

Comment: Tente armazenar os dados no array usando var a = array[""entre aspas"", "..."]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optei por diminuir o código da sua função calculaValor() e também criei valores fictícios para altura e largura. Desta forma o calculo é realizado.

```
<script>
    function calculaValores(modelo, altura, largura) {
        var area = altura * largura;
        var calc = parseFloat((area * modelo).toFixed(2));
        var valor = parseFloat((area * 120).toFixed(2));
        document.getElementById('exibe').innerHTML = "<b>Quantidade de Placas: " + calc + "<br> Valor Instalação: " +
            valor + "</b>";
        document.calculaOrc.submit;
    }

    function calculaValor() {

        var placa = document.getElementById('calcOrcamento').value;

        var altura = document.getElementById('altura').value;
        var largura = document.getElementById('largura').value;

        calculaValores(placa, altura, largura);
        }

    function validaModelo(modelo) {
        var msg = "Modelo Inválido.";
        var info = "Selecionar um Modelo";

        if (modelo.value == '') {
            estilizandoErro(modelo, msg, info);
        }
    }

    function estilizandoErro(variavel, msg, info) {
        variavel.value = "";
        variavel.placeholder = msg;
        variavel.style.borderColor = "#ff0000";
        variavel.style.outline = "#ff0000";
        variavel.focus();
        variavel.onkeydown = function keydown_nome() {
            variavel.placeholder = info;
            variavel.style.borderColor = "#999999";
            variavel.style.outline = null;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Valeu Mário, funcionou aqui.

Comment: Thanks Guilherme!!